# Change a WPF Grid to have the origin in the bottom left corner

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

If I have a control like this:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">  
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="One, One" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="One, Two" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="One, Three" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Two, One" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Two, Two" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="Two, Three" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="Three, One" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="Three, Two" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="Three, Three" />
</Grid>
```

I will get a grid that looks like this:

```
___________________________________________  
| One, One   | Two, One   |  Three, One   |
-------------------------------------------
| One, Two   | Two, Two   |  Three, Two   |
-------------------------------------------
| One, Three | Two, Three |  Three, Three |
-------------------------------------------
```

Is there anything I can do (short of changing up all my `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` settings) to get this grid to show like this:

```
___________________________________________  
| One, Three | Two, Three |  Three, Three |
-------------------------------------------
| One, Two   | Two, Two   |  Three, Two   |
-------------------------------------------
| One, One   | Two, One   |  Three, One   |
-------------------------------------------
```

Basically I want to change the point of origin from the top left corner to the bottom left corner.

(Note: My real scenario has a 42 x 30 grid with many visual components bound to the grid (by row, column and spans).  This question is my attempt to avoid transforming my bound data manually.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with layout transformations. **EDIT: Simplified the transformations to be a single transformation. As it turns out, the matrix tranformation for the grid matches that for each text block**

Here's an example screenshot:

[image: Example]

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MatrixTransform>
                        <MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                            <Matrix M11="1" M12="0" M21="0" M22="-1"  />
                        </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                    </MatrixTransform>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <MatrixTransform>
            <MatrixTransform.Matrix>
                <Matrix M11="1" M12="0" M21="0" M22="-1"  />
            </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
        </MatrixTransform>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="One, One"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="One, Two"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="One, Three"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Two, One" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Two, Two" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="Two, Three" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="Three, One" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="Three, Two" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="Three, Three" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you!

Comment: This was a fun one! My gut instinct was it was impossible, and I almost wrote that in. Then decided to do some research and got to apply some linear algebra to get it working :)

Comment: Cool. It's hard to believe this =) Does it work for different-sized cells?

Comment: It should work for any shape of the cells. It seems like LayoutTransform is a property on a lot of different controls, so you can apply transformations to any control that supports it. I think that this is because WPF UI is drawn with Direct2D which allows for these kind of effects

Comment: What an awesome solution. Nice answer mate. `LayoutTransform` is available on any `FrameworkElement`